# Strange behavior on browser tab change vs. page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Observed on Chrome and Microsoft Edge. Other browsers not tested.

I have an element that loads with the CSS attributes `opacity` and `visibility` so that it's hidden. On a mouse hover, with `:hover`, those are changed back to `visible` and `1`.

- On page load, this element is not aligned as it should be. It just isn't.
- But when I switch tabs, this misalignment is corrected.
- Page refresh observes the same behavior as page load.

Things to note. The element has its size set. But it inherits its parent's size. If the element is loaded with its native size - these issues are not observed.

Can I call a function that refreshes the page as if tab was switched after loading is done?

The CSS:

```css
.my-hover-class {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    opacity: 0 !important; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out !important;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out !important;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out !important;
}

.rev_slider:hover .my-hover-class {
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your markup and CSS.  _"Can i call a function that refreshes the page as if tab was switched after loading is done?"_  Maybe, but it'd be better to fix the underlying problem.

Comment: added CSS code. Markup is a whole different story as it's a revolution slider on top of wordpress...